# Error: incorrect number of arguments expected 1

Tags: actionscript, arguments

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong with this code?

```
Public function Main
{
   Var _myScreens:Screens = new Screens();
   This.addChild(_myScreens);
}
```

After compilation, I get the error

> Error: incorrect number of arguments expected 1

Comment: It would appear that Screens expects a parameter to be passed. Whats in Screens class?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Screens class needs 1 argument to be passed on creation of a new Screens object.

Also you should have:

```
public function Main() 
{
    ...
}
```